# How to sort an object based on timestamp?

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, timestamp, momentjs

I have a message JSON object where for each message there is a timeStamp of when it was submitted. I would like to sort that object based on the timeStamp.

For example:

```js
"Messages": {
  "message1": {
    "msg"       : "I'm trying to make this work",
    "timeStamp" : "2018-02-15T06:24:44.12+00:00"
  },
  "message2": {
    "msg"       : "I really need your help SO!",
    "timeStamp" : "2018-03-01T13:57:27+00:00"  
  },
  "message3": {
    "msg"       : "Please assist me dude!",
    "timeStamp" : "2018-03-01T11:57:27+00:00"
  }
}
```

The timeStamp generated is from [**`momentjs`**](https://momentjs.com/)
using `moment().format();`.

The issue is, I'm not really sure how to filter an object based on that timestamp format.

I currently have no working example and cant think of a better way.

## Why do I need this?

I'm using this object to show messages between two people, but the messages need to be in order based on time.

## Can't you just change the format and make it simple?

No because, currently my whole application is based on that format, and changing it will cause more issues.

## Update

I've forgotten mention that the format of the output must be an object after sorting (where most recent is first item)

Comment: why is not necessary, but how should look the object after *sorting* and what have you tried?

Comment: Have a look here [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: I was really hoping to show what I have so far, but I honestly don't have anything. Primarily because I'm not even sure how to sort based date @NinaScholz

Answer (score 0):

This outputs the messages sorted most recent first as an array... you could rebuild the object if you really need to.

```
const json = {
    "Messages": {
        "message1": {
            "msg"       : "I'm trying to make this work",
            "timeStamp" : "2018-02-15T06:24:44.12+00:00"
        },
        "message2": {
            "msg"       : "I really need your help SO!",
            "timeStamp" : "2018-03-01T13:57:27+00:00"  
        },
        "message3": {
            "msg"       : "Please assist me dude!",
            "timeStamp" : "2018-03-01T11:57:27+00:00"
        }
    }
}

const messageIds = Object.keys(json.Messages)

const messages = messageIds.map(id => json.Messages[id]).sort((a, b) =>
    a.timeStamp < b.timeStamp ? 1 : -1
)

console.log(JSON.stringify(messages, null, 4))
```

Comment: the string are not in same format.  24:44.12  on first

Comment: they were in your example.  use moment(...).toISOString() and they will be sortable as strings.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you did. Let me check this

Comment: you can also compare two moment instances.... it will just use .valueOf()

Answer (score 0):

you can revive you dates as follows:
If you messages are in a variable: foo

```
foo =  {
  "message1": {
    "msg"       : "I'm trying to make this work",
    "timeStamp" : "2018-02-15T06:24:44.12+00:00"
  },
  "message2": {
    "msg"       : "I really need your help SO!",
    "timeStamp" : "2018-03-01T13:57:27+00:00"  
  },
  "message3": {
    "msg"       : "Please assist me dude!",
    "timeStamp" : "2018-03-01T11:57:27+00:00"
  }
}
```

Then this will add a new property wihch you can sort on (datetime)

```
foo = Object.keys(foo).map(key => { return Object.assign({}, foo[key], {datetime: new Date(foo[key].timeStamp)}) });
```

you can get the messages in order as follows:

```
const sortedMessges = Object.keys(foo).map(key => foo[key]).sort((a, b) =>
    a.datetime< b.datetime ? 1 : -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort` and then `map` the sorted array.

```js
var obj = {"Messages": {  "message1": {    "msg"       : "I'm trying to make this work",    "timeStamp" : "2018-02-15T06:24:44.12+00:00"  },  "message2": {    "msg"       : "I really need your help SO!",    "timeStamp" : "2018-03-01T13:57:27+00:00"    },  "message3": {    "msg"       : "Please assist me dude!",    "timeStamp" : "2018-01-01T11:57:27+00:00"  }}};

var result = Object.keys(obj.Messages)
                   .sort((a, b) => Date.parse(obj.Messages[a].timeStamp) - Date.parse(obj.Messages[b].timeStamp))
                   .map(k => ({ [k]: obj.Messages[k] }) );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily, through a representation `repr` function and a `TrueSet`.

After importing the class `TrueSet` from the library [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier/)

```
import { TrueSet } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import { ORDER } from "@ut8pia/classifier/global.js";
```

and posing:

```
const 
    srcMsgs = {

        "message1": {
            "msg"       : "I'm trying to make this work",
            "timeStamp" : "2018-02-15T06:24:44.12+00:00"
        },

        "message2": {
            "msg"       : "I really need your help SO!",
            "timeStamp" : "2018-03-01T13:57:27+00:00"  
        },

        "message3": {
            "msg"       : "Please assist me dude!",
            "timeStamp" : "2018-6-03-01T11:57:27+00:00"
        }
    }
```

you can simply define the representation `repr` function, instantiate the `TrueSet` and add all the msgs into it:

```
const
    repr = msg => new Date(msg.timeStamp),

    set = TrueSet.of(repr, ORDER.ASCENDING, ORDER.INSERTION)
        .letAll(Object.values(srcMsgs))
```

All the messages are automatically sorted by `timeStamp`, in ascending order. If two messages share the same `timeStamp`, they are sorted by order of insertion.

To create a `trgMsgs` object, corresponding to the initial `srcMsgs` object, you can simply interate over the `TrueSet` and store each message in the incremental property `'message' + i` of the `trgMsgs` object.

```
const 
    trgMsgs = Array.from(set)
        .reduce((trg, msg, i) => {
           trg["message" + i] = msg;
           return trg
        }, {})
```